# Using more than one sheet for a pivot table in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-docs

I'm trying to link three spreadsheets in Google Sheets by using the pivot tables functionality.

The problem that i have now is that i don't find a way to pull the data for more than one sheet. I can only operate the Pivot table with the information coming from only one.
I have researched quite a lot, but my impression so far is that the documentation available for Google Docs is not so extensive at some point.

Basically what i need to do is the following:

Table 1(main):

Car Name | ModelId | ColorID

ford |    1    |   1

fiat |    2    |   2

Table 2:

ModelID | Name

    1    |   mustang

    2    |   bravo

Table 3:

ColorID | Name

    1    |   Red

    2    |   Blue

Resulting pivot table:

 Car Name | Model| Color

ford |    mustang    |   Red

fiat |    bravo    |   Blue

In SQL statements i'm basically trying to simulate a JOIN.
I also could write a javascript script but i would like to know if there is a simple way to achieve this without coding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This formula reproduces your example output and will update if more records are added to the 3 tables:

`={"CarName","Model","Color";
Table1!A2:A,
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Table1!B2:B,Table2!A:B,2,0))),
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Table1!C2:C,Table3!A:B,2,0)))}`

[This example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lt1x29ovVjzIcWdmaGvNNirQPP1ZWFZMDcHg6voZEVc/edit#gid=2103900918) shows the formula working.